# How to use LIKE keyword in group by clause. MySQl

Tags: mysql, yii

I executed a query and got table like this:-

```
query=select column_1, column_2 from @Table_name where id in (818, 1213, 114)
```

table:

```
**column_1** | **column_2**
----------------------------
   vinod     |  Agarwal
   vinod     |  Agarwal
   vinod kr. |  Agarwal
```

If I change query like this
select column_1, column_2 from @Table_name where id in (818, 1213, 114) group by column_1, column_2

then I got as

```
**column_1** | **column_2**
----------------------------
   vinod     |  Agarwal
   vinod kr. |  Agarwal
```

but I want only one record in my resultant table. Any solution for this. Thanx

Comment: **How to use LIKE keyword in group by clause. MySQl** and your question body both does not match? what do you want really a like clause or else and what you have tries with the LIKE clause in your statement which does not work

Comment: You can use DISTINCT keyword on column2. Although this is a mere guess as your question is not at all clear!!!

Comment: How on earth do you expect one result on that data?

Comment: As It is clear from the table that all the records are duplicates and associated with a single person, So I want just a single record.

Comment: @RahulTripathi:- above table is just a demo, actually I have a database of 10,000 persons, In which there are too many duplicate entries, which differ from each other slightly. 
So I can't use distinct keyword.

Comment: @NetStarter:- I think that this can be done using like keyword, but I don;t know how to use it here.

Comment: @vinod **I want only one record in my resultant table** is that mean you need a single record from the whole table or you need a record which is Distinct or you need to select only the top most record there are lots of possibilities of the above statement can you please tell us exactly what you need ?

Answer (score 1):

Your own solution is pretty correct. Simply use

```
SELECT 
  column_1, 
  column_2 
FROM 
  @Table_name 
WHERE
  id IN (818, 1213, 114) 
GROUP BY 
  column_2
```

Please consider writing key words in uppercase, its much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

since your question and your desired output are unclear.  this will give one record

```
     group by column_2
```